# How to properly wrap a C library with Python CFFI

Tags: python, c, python-cffi

I am trying to wrap a very simple C library containing only two .C source files: *dbc2dbf.c* and *blast.c*

I am doing the following (from the documentation):

```
import os
from cffi import FFI
blastbuilder = FFI()
ffibuilder = FFI()
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "c-src/blast.c")) as f:
    blastbuilder.set_source("blast", f.read(), libraries=["c"])
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "c-src/blast.h")) as f:
    blastbuilder.cdef(f.read())
blastbuilder.compile(verbose=True)

with open('c-src/dbc2dbf.c','r') as f:
    ffibuilder.set_source("_readdbc",
                          f.read(),
                          libraries=["c"])

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "c-src/blast.h")) as f:
    ffibuilder.cdef(f.read(), override=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # ffibuilder.include(blastbuilder)
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

This is not quite working. I think I am not including *blast.c* correctly;

can anyone help?

Comment: Unsure why you need two instances of ``FFI()``.  This is certainly not in the documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution (tested):

```
import os
from cffi import FFI

ffibuilder = FFI()

PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'c-src/dbc2dbf.c'),'r') as f:
    ffibuilder.set_source("_readdbc",
                          f.read(),
                          libraries=["c"],
                          sources=[os.path.join(PATH, "c-src/blast.c")],
                          include_dirs=[os.path.join(PATH, "c-src/")]
                          )
ffibuilder.cdef(
    """
    static unsigned inf(void *how, unsigned char **buf);
    static int outf(void *how, unsigned char *buf, unsigned len);
    void dbc2dbf(char** input_file, char** output_file);
    """
)

with open(os.path.join(PATH, "c-src/blast.h")) as f:
    ffibuilder.cdef(f.read(), override=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

Comment: I think I could still get rid of the cdef on 'blast.h' since I don't need to expose any function from there.

Comment: I should mention that without @armin-rigo help I wouldn't find this solution! Thanks again!